# BusinessHours methods not compiling

Tags: apex, trigger, businesshours

For some reason when I attempt to use the `BusinessHours.isWithin` method within Salesforce I get the following error:

```
Compile failure on line 4, column 34: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void isWithin(Id, Datetime) from the type BusinessHours
```

Here is the simple code I used to generate this error in anonymous apex:

```
BusinessHours businessHours = [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE IsDefault=TRUE];
System.debug('Business Hours:' + businessHours);

Boolean isWithin = BusinessHours.isWithin(businessHours.Id, System.now());
System.debug('isWithin:' + isWithin);
```

Any ideas on why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have introduced a naming conflict here:

```
BusinessHours businessHours = [...];
```

Any lines below this will reference the record you have queried, not the class you are trying to reference. You can either fix it by naming your record something else and avoiding the conflict altogether, or referencing the `BusinessHours` class prefixed with `System.` to disambiguate.

```
Boolean isWithin = System.BusinessHours.isWthin(...);
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple. Thank you!